# Como calcular horas trabajadas en horario especifico de nocturnidad, Excel

Tags: excel

estoy implementando una tabla de horarios en excel, y necesito una funcion que me calcule las horas nocturnas trabajadas pero las mismas solo son consideradas nocturnas en el caso de trabajar 5h o mas en el rango de 22:00 a las 6:00am

Por ejemplo:
1): Si trabajo en el horario de 12:00 (del medio dia) -17:00 he trabajado 5h pero no se encuentran en el rango de 22:00 - 6:00am por lo que no necesito que sean contempladas por la funcion.

2): Si trabajo en el horario de 19:00-4:00am he trabajado 9h pero solo 6h en el rango especificado anteriormente, esto tambien necesito que sea contemplado por la funcion.

3): Si trabajo en el horario de 00:00-3:00 he trabajado 3h y todas en el rango especificado pero no llegan a las 5h minimas dentro de se horario.

Llegue a la conclusion de algunas condiciones estrictas que tienen que cumplir los horarios de entrada y salida, bueno, en primer lugar **las  horas trabajadas en ese dia tiene que se mayor o igual a 5h**. Luego **la hora de salida tiene que ser mayor o igual a las 3:00am** debido a que es el minimo caso que cumpla 5h dentro del rango 22:00 - 6:00am.
Pero claro, aqui surgen mas problemas, porque por ejemplo con estas restricciones no es suficiente ya que si cumplo el horario de 13:00-18:00, he trabajado mas de 5h y he salido despues de las 3:00am entonces en la funcion que he hecho me la cuenta como horas nocturnas...

Cabe aclarar que el formato que estoy usando es una tabla en las que tengo las horas de entrada, las horas de salida, horas trabajadas. Igualmente adjuntare foto de la tabla con algunos horarios para ejemplo y mejor visualizacion.

Por ultimo les dejo la ultima funcion a la que llegue (tal vez les ayuda a ayudarme):

```
=SI([@[1ra Salida]]>=$N$4;SI([@[Horas trabajadas]]>=$N$3;SI([@[1ra Entrada]]<=$C$39;SI([@[1ra Salida]]<=$N$5;(([@[1ra Salida]]+$R$11)-($C$39+$R$11) + 1);(($N$5+$R$11)-($C$39+$R$11) + 1));SI([@[1ra Salida]]<=$N$5;[@[Horas trabajadas]];(($N$5+$R$11)-([@[1ra Entrada]]+$R$11) + 1)));"No llega a 5h trabajadas");"No sale despues de las 3:00")
```

Nota:

```
      $N$4 = 3:00
      $N$3 = 5:00
      $C$39 = 22:00
      $R$11 = 12:00
```

Captura antes mencionada:
[image: La funcion que antes les deje es la que se encuentra en la columna "Nocturnidades"]

Espero que puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias a tod@s!

Comment: De 12 am a 17 tenes 17 horas

Comment: Tienes razon, me confundi con le tipo de horario, me referia de 12 del mediodia a 17 de la tarde, ya modifico la pregunta, gracias por notificarme del error!

Comment: Es mejor que trabajes con la fecha completa y no solo la hora, a efectos de cálculos. Piensa que cuando alguien entra a trabajar, por ejemplo, a las 19:00 y salgo a las 04:00, he cambiado de día. Entré a trabajar a las 19:00 del día X, pero salgo a las 04:00:00 del día x+1. Eso te facilitará mucho los cálculos.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Si, tienes razon, en el camino a intentar resolver esta tabla, me he dado cuenta de eso, pero los datos son extraidos de un reloj electronico en el que los empleados marcan su hora de entrada y salida, y a fin de mes retiro los datos y los copio a esta tabla con el fin de sacar datos mas procesados. Y el formato no lo puedo cambiar de forma rapida, o por lo menos que yo sepa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que esta funcion lo hace. La funciona suponga que no trabajan despues de 1:00 PM si tiene horas de noche.

`=IF(AND(B2>0.13,B2<0.54,(MIN(0.25,B2)-IF(A2<0.25,A2,0)+IF(A2>=0.25,MIN(1-0.9167,1-A2),0))>0.2083),(MIN(0.25,B2)-IF(A2<0.25,A2,0)+IF(A2>=0.25,MIN(1-0.9167,1-A2),0))*24,"No llega a 5h")`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu rapida respuesta, esta formula soluciona el problema en su generalidad, lo unico que me genera confusion es que el resultado que libera la formula no lo hace en el formato de hora "hh:mm" por ejemplo si entro a las 23:00 y salio a las 4:25 trabajo 5:25 en el horario de nocturnidad por lo que la funcion deberia liberar ese mismo valor, pero tu funcion entrega el valor de 5,42, **algun consejo para que quede en formato hh:mm ** . Sin ser ese pequeno detalle, el resto de la solucion estaria correcta. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes eliminar el *24 y cambiar el formato al tiempo para mostrarlo en el formato hh:mm

Comment: listo, muchas gracias, solucianado todo. Abrazo!